# Change color of a span on hover with CSS

Tags: html, css

I know what is the right syntax to change the color attribute of a span but I can't reproduce this behaviour and I don't know why

This is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 btn">

                    <table class="table panelc" id="panelc">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <span class="bpost-parcellocker" style="color: #EF2637; font-size: 90px; "></span>

                              </td>
                              <td class="text-center text-nowrap">
                                Vanaf<br>€4,00
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                Een pakjesautomaat
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>


            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.table.panelc:hover, .table.panelc:hover span  {
    background-color: #EF2637;
    color: white;
 }
```

Only the content of the table will be changed but not the color for the span, why ? I did several attempts and the selector is correct.

Indeed If I try to change the background of the span everything works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have your inline style do as follow:

```
.table.panelc:hover, .table.panelc:hover span  {
  background-color: #EF2637;
  color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because inline style has higher specificity than the one in your css.

Read more about CSS specificity here: http://cssspecificity.com/